# How to use NVL or COALESCE in native query for list of values in Spring Data JPA

Tags: sql, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using native query as follows which fetches data from multiple tables.
I also want to perform filtering on it based on users input. User can select either none, one or multiple checkboxes in filter menu based on which my query should return the record.
I have tried both the approaches like:

```
src_region.region_id NVL(:regionIds,src_region.region_id )
src_region.region_id in(:regionIds) OR COALESCE (:regionIds)IS NULL)
```

But for both of them I am getting errors as I am sending List values.

```
public interface dbRepository
{
  public static final String dbQuery = "select * from
    (select src_data.*,
            trg_data.*
    from
    (select reg.region_id,reg.region_name,
            ctry.country_id,ctry.country_name
    from src_region reg,src_ctry ctry
    where reg.region_id=ctry.region_id
    AND src_region.region_id in(:regionIds) OR COALESCE (:regionIds)IS NULL) src_data,
    
    (select md.module_id,reg.module_name,
            ctry.country_id,ctry.country_name
    from trg_module md,trg_ctry ctry
    where md.module_id=ctry.country_id
    AND ctry.country_id in(:countryIds) OR COALESCE (:countryIds)IS NULL) trg_data
ORDER BY src_data.region_id ";

  @Query( value = dbQuery, nativeQuery = true )
List<Object[]> findBySorceOrTarget( @Param( "regionIds" ) List<Long> regionIds, @Param( "countryIds" ) List<Long> countryIds );

}
```

User may on may not send values. Also, rather than sending multiple values, they can also send only one value. What is the better way to pass list of values to parameters in native query?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, that should be

```
AND (src_region.region_id = :regionIds or :regionIds IS NULL)
```

---

However, if you can select multiple values, then `=` won't be OK - you'll have to switch to `in` (as code you posted suggests). Though, you can't do it that way as you'll get *nothing* as a result - you'll have to split those values into rows.

Something like this (presuming that values in `:regionIds` are comma-separated, such as `1,2,5`:

```
and (src_region.region_id in (select regexp_substr(:regionIds, '[^,]+', 1, level)
                              from dual
                              connect by level <= regexp_count(:regionIds, ',') + 1
                             )
     or :regionIds is null)
```